# How do I get an image by URL? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, image

I am working on a script and I need to change an image.
The image has no class and I cannot set a class for it.
How can I get the image by url and be able to edit it?
Sort of like document.getElementById(); but with the image url.
I have tried using getElementsByClass but that didn't work.

Comment: `querySelector()`

Comment: Use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) with an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Attribute_selectors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select based on the `src` attribute.

```
const img = document.querySelector('img[src=' + url + ']');
```